# How do i limit the amount of LI in using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the `jQuery UI` to develop a drag and drop favourites UI, I want to limit the amount of LI's (limited to 5) dropped in a specific region, and replace current ones if a user drop one over the other. How can this be done? I'm currently using a modified version of the photomanager on the `jQuery UI` site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check how many LI's are in the region and from 5+ you replace the actual LI's.
Lets see:

```
On Drop event:
   if($("#region li").length<5){
      //do your normal drop handling
   }else{
      //replace one of the actual li's with the dragged one
   }
```

is that helpful?

Comment: Thanks but it didn't work really, here is my code

  `if($("#favourites li").length<5){
    $favourites.droppable({
 accept: '#icon-gallery ul > li',
 drop: function(ev, ui) {
deleteImage(ui.draggable);
}
});
}else{
$favourites.droppable({deactivate: '#icon-gallery ul > li',});
}
`

Comment: I realized I was applying the if statement to the drag event and not the drop event

Answer (score 1):

I recently did this in some kind of different way. Instead of preventing the area to be droppable, I would just pick up any surplus LI, and append it back to the pool of possibles by just appending back the last child

```
$('#pool').append($('#container li:last-child'));
```

See if this approach fits you ..